# request.get() extremely slow

Tags: python, python-requests, pyqt6

**Situation**- I have 144 kmls with +-1000 image urls per kml and I need all of those photos

**Goal**- To create a application that reads kml files, extracts url for any photos that are associated with a point an then to download the image.

**problem**- The requests.get() function is taking extremely long, a few minutes per request. The program used to work for a few tests and then at some point all the request slowed down completely. I think I'm being rate limited, but I'm not sure

code:

**Interface.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="windowModality">
   <enum>Qt::ApplicationModal</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>291</width>
    <height>513</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>291</width>
    <height>513</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>291</width>
    <height>513</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>KML Photo downloader</string>
  </property>
  <property name="tabShape">
   <enum>QTabWidget::Triangular</enum>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QListWidget" name="list_selection">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>251</width>
      <height>192</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QProgressBar" name="progress_current">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>390</y>
      <width>271</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="value">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="textVisible">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="invertedAppearance">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="textDirection">
     <enum>QProgressBar::BottomToTop</enum>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="button_browse">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>200</x>
      <y>220</y>
      <width>71</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Browse</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="button_remove">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>120</x>
      <y>220</y>
      <width>71</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Remove</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QProgressBar" name="progress_overall">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>440</y>
      <width>271</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="value">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="textVisible">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>370</y>
      <width>81</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Current Project</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>420</y>
      <width>91</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Overall Progress</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="button_start">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>210</x>
      <y>470</y>
      <width>71</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Start</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="button_close">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>130</x>
      <y>470</y>
      <width>71</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Close</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QListWidget" name="list_log">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>270</y>
      <width>251</width>
      <height>91</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>271</width>
      <height>251</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string>Select Files to download:</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>250</y>
      <width>271</width>
      <height>121</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string>Log</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <zorder>groupBox_2</zorder>
   <zorder>groupBox</zorder>
   <zorder>list_selection</zorder>
   <zorder>progress_current</zorder>
   <zorder>button_browse</zorder>
   <zorder>button_remove</zorder>
   <zorder>progress_overall</zorder>
   <zorder>label</zorder>
   <zorder>label_2</zorder>
   <zorder>button_start</zorder>
   <zorder>button_close</zorder>
   <zorder>list_log</zorder>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**Main.py**

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel, QListWidget, QProgressBar, QPushButton
from PyQt6 import uic
import sys
import functions
from tkinter import filedialog
from PyQt6.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QThreadPool, QTimer
from test import download_class


class window_ui(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(window_ui, self).__init__()

        #load the UI files:
        uic.loadUi("interface.ui", self)

        #New Thread
        self.thread_manager = QThreadPool()

        #Define widegets:
        self.button_browse = self.findChild(QPushButton, "button_browse")
        self.button_remove = self.findChild(QPushButton, "button_remove")
        self.button_start = self.findChild(QPushButton, "button_start")
        self.button_close = self.findChild(QPushButton, "button_close")
        self.list_selection = self.findChild(QListWidget, "list_selection")
        self.list_log = self.findChild(QListWidget, "list_log")
        self.progress_current = self.findChild(QProgressBar, "progress_current")
        self.progress_overall = self.findChild(QProgressBar, "progress_overall")

        #Running commands:
        self.button_browse.clicked.connect(self.browseFiles)
        
        self.button_close.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.button_start.clicked.connect(self.downloadfiles_thread)
        
        #Display the app:
        self.show()
    
    # Function for opening the
    # file explorer window
    def browseFiles(self):
        filenames = filedialog.askopenfilename(multiple=True,
                                          initialdir = "/",
                                          title = "Select a File",
                                          filetypes = (("KML files",
                                                        "*.kml*"),
                                                       ("all files",
                                                        "*.*")))
        # Change label contents 
        for index, filename in enumerate(filenames): 
            #list_file_explorer.insert(index, filename)
            self.list_selection.insertItem(index, filename)
    
    #function to run the conversion
    @pyqtSlot()
    def downloadfiles(self):
        filenames = [self.list_selection.item(i).text() for i in range(self.list_selection.count())]
        self.progress_overall.setMaximum(len(filenames))
        
        for index, filename in enumerate(filenames):
            functions.download(self, filename)
            self.progress_overall.setValue(index + 1)
            
    #Start the download thread
    @pyqtSlot()
    def downloadfiles_thread(self):
        self.thread_manager.start(self.downloadfiles)


#Initialize App
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
UIWindow = window_ui()
app.exec()
```

**Functions.py**

```
import shutil
import urllib
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BSHTML
from pykml import parser
from pykml.factory import nsmap
import threading
from time import sleep
from requests.exceptions import Timeout
from requests.exceptions import ConnectTimeout
import random
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request
import os
from PyQt6 import QtCore
import random


def download(window, filename):
    #folder name
    folder_name = os.path.basename(filename)
    folder_name = os.path.splitext(folder_name)
    folder_name = folder_name[0]
    #setup file directory
    rel_directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'Photos', folder_name)
    if not os.path.exists(rel_directory):
        os.makedirs(rel_directory)

    namespace = {"ns": nsmap[None]}
    url_tuple = ()
    with open(filename) as f:
        root = parser.parse(f).getroot()
        pms = root.findall(".//ns:Placemark", namespaces=namespace)
    for pm in pms:
        name = pm.name
        if isinstance(name.text, str):
            name = name.text + '.png'
            directory_list = dir(pm)
            if 'description' in directory_list:
                description = pm.description
                source_text = description.text
                soup = BSHTML(source_text, 'html.parser')
                images = soup.findAll('img')
                for image in images:
                    url = image['src']
                    #create file name
                    point = pm.Point
                    coordinate = point.coordinates
                    coordinate = coordinate.text
                    coordinate = re.findall(r'\d+', coordinate)
                    coordinate = ','.join(coordinate) + '.png'
                    #list creation
                    url_dict = {'url' : url, 'name' : coordinate}
                    url_tuple = list(url_tuple)
                    url_tuple.append(url_dict)
                    url_tuple = tuple(url_tuple)

    #Update the current progressbar maximum              
    window.progress_current.setMaximum(len(url_tuple))
    
    print(f'Total numbers: {len(url_tuple)}')

    #Create a thread pool to try and limit the amount of requests
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 10) as executor:
        future_to_url = {executor.submit(saveimage, window, url['url'], url['name'], rel_directory): url for url in url_tuple}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
            url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        
def saveimage(window, url, coordinate, rel_directory):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    except ConnectTimeout:
        print(url)
    except Timeout:
        print(url)
    file_name = os.path.join(rel_directory, coordinate)
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
        num = window.progress_current.value()
        window.progress_current.setValue(num + 1)
        print (f'Proccesses Completed {num + 1}')
        num = num + 1
    del response
```

Do you guys have any idea what the cause could be?

I tried setting up a thread pool to ensure I'm not sending through too many request, I expected the files to download at a reasonable rate and the result was incredibly slow

Comment: Use [QNetworkAccessManager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnetworkaccessmanager.html).

Comment: As an aside, in `saveimage` you continue to process `response` even after an exception is raised. Since the `response` variable wasn't assigned in that case, the best you could hope for is erroneously saving the previous response agian. Your exception handers should `return`.

Comment: Thanks @musicamante - I'll go through the documentation and see if I can get it to work - I'll report back once I've tried it